# Suggestion for obesity weight loss program

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, bellyfat, burn-fat

I'm a software engineer, and have to sit at my desk for long periods of time. I don't have any disease, but my weight has increased. At the age of 29, my weight is 89 kg , while my height is 167 cm. I want to lose weight, especially my abdomen.

Since I'm far from fit, I am asking for a program that starts with simple exercises, but gets extreme in a few weeks.

I found "The Biggest Loser" series on Amazon, which seemed promising. But I thought to ask here first before buying anything.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-can-an-overweight-engineer-get-back-in-shape) may help you get started.  It is specific to someone else, but a lot of the info will apply to you too.  Also, the person who asked gives a successful update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I would have a physical to make sure you are healthy enough to start an exercise program.

The one statement in your question that concerns me is the "get extreme in a few weeks". Being fit is not a short, one shot deal that you can accomplish in a couple of months and boom, everything is grand. It's a long (hopefully lifelong) process that builds upon itself. If you start out and then get extreme very quickly, then it's likely that you will either burn out or incur injury that returns you to the sedentary life.

I would recommend starting out by simply walking a few times a week, building up to where you can easily walk 30 minutes, 3-4 times a week. Add to this a weightlifting program such as [Stronglifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/).

Your abdominal muscles may get very fit, but you won't be able to see them until you lose the excess weight. That means that you also have to start paying attention to your diet, which is how much and what you eat.

You don't really need to buy anything, most of the resources you are going to need are available via web sources, and getting out and exercising costs nothing except maybe some gym fees.

Comment: If you've got the space and the money though, I doesn't hurt to get yourself a barbell and a squat rack.