# Out of shape and in need of help

Tags: diet, workout-routines

I am a gamer, and I used to be 150lb's and my weight has increased to about 215lb's. What sort of exercise routine and diet should I try to set up to lose weight and become a bit more healthy? keep in mind, I have not actually exercised in a year or two.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Honestly, a lot of guys already asked what you are asking. Maybe you should just search the site for similar questions? Like this one, and many more: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-can-an-overweight-engineer-get-back-in-shape?rq=1 if a good search leaves you with more qeustions, remember to include your age, height and all other details that may prove useful for us