# I am overweight and I want to lose weight but I don't know how!

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, fat, bellyfat, burn-fat

About me , I am 25 year old male , with 100+ kilo weight, a pot belly that is lots of disappointment when I am in any trial room while shopping clothes .

I am currently aiming to get fit and have been going outdoors for jogging as well as fast walking for 1 hours and on an alternative day I do exercises.

I don't want this weight losing process to be super rapid , I want effective one but I need to lose the weight around whole upper body as fast as you can suggest.

There are lots of guide over the internet I tried to find but nothing comes for an fat/overweight dude so I am wishing someone could tell me how am I supposed to get fit and lose weight?

Comment: @SeanDuggan Actually, precise duplicate. Thanks for pointing out. Only difference is I am 5'11"

Comment: If you're out exercising, you've got a good start. The next step is simply to reduce your caloric intake to below what you're burning. Find out what your BMR (Basal Metabolic Rate) is (typically around 2200 calories per day) is and track your food input. Don't worry about including exercise in there. Frankly, most people don't burn that much with casual exercise. Your bigger problem is not eating more than you burn, which is a natural human reaction.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I walk and run , i.e 25:75 , running to the walking. But my heart can't keep up with the running and I don't feel walking doe anything good. I have included more fruits and salads into diet. I surfed net for some good exercises but those seem pretty tough for me. Hence I came here looking as to some exercise that are effective and I could do. Like when doing abs exercise I can even lift myself to the 30 degree and I am scared of over doing or pushing and hurting self

Comment: Ah. So you're looking for low-impact exercises that will help burn calories and build muscles? With this group, weightlifting will probably be the suggestion. It's accessible for most people, highly regulated, and easy to perform consistently on a strict plan such as 5x5 or StrongLifts. It doesn't generally stress joints all that much, and the lean muscle you build slightly boosts your metabolic rate.

Comment: That said, walking actually is a decent exercise, and it's one of the safer ones. It doesn't burn a lot of calories quickly, but it's something which most people can sustain for long amounts of time. Vary your route, preferably with different terrain and slopes. Listening to a book on tape, music, or the radio, can all be ways to combat boredom, but I'd advise keeping only one earbud in at a time so that you can hear environmental dangers, and always be wary of traffic.

Comment: @SeanDuggan not to disappoint you but this is first time in life I have thought about fitness and I am complete noob (if that doesn't offend anyone). All the terms you have used are quite foreign to me. I promise to learn but what exactly is 5x5 or strong lift? I certainly have no idea , just myths, and one of them is weight light is for gaining weight and not losing it!

Comment: Also, see [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6/exercises-for-a-programmer-sitting-by-the-pc-all-day/363#363), and [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-can-an-overweight-engineer-get-back-in-shape)