# How to reduce fatigue after office?

Tags: exercise, diet, sleep, water, brain

I work 9-6 in a software company. There's not much physical movement in office. I experience fatigue on reaching home. What can I do on weekends and even weekdays so that I don't feel tired after coming home from office?

This question is not related to fat loss / weight loss. But related to fatigue.

Comment: You [cross-posted this question in "Health"](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/12725/how-to-reduce-fatigue-after-office).  I think it belongs there only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an overweight engineer get back in shape?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-can-an-overweight-engineer-get-back-in-shape)

Answer (score 5):

You’d be amazed how much more productive and energized you feel after starting a strength and cardio training regimen.  As you’re just starting out, **developing consistency is *far more important* than what exercises you do**.

> **Discipline is everything.**

**Defined as:** *Control gained by enforcing obedience or order: orderly or prescribed conduct or pattern of behavior: self-control.*

As health is not temporary, approach it with the mindset you’re making a lifelong change. I'd recommended starting doing the following:

---

- Each week **start by writing down 3 days** *(say Monday, Wednesday and
  Friday)* you’re going to workout.
- **DON’T go home after work on a workout day**.  You’ll ***never*** end up going back out. Bring your gym stuff with you.
- You’ll run into days you really **don’t feel like it** – that’s
  normal.  ***Still go, get changed and if after 15 minutes you still
  don’t feel like exercising – leave.***

Need help developing an exercise plan?  That’s the easy part. Google one or hire a trainer to help you out.

Obviously, diet plays an important role too but the **carryover effect** from the **discipline developed is your initial focus** will help directly with dietary changes.

---

> **Bottom line:**

There is a tremendous amount of research linking exercise to an ***increase in energy and productivity***.

**Discipline** has been shown to be **most important aspect of habit development and therefore should be developed first**.

Answer (score 1):

One primary reason for fatigue is due to lack of oxygen supply to cells. So, you should make sure you are breathing properly (ie. deep inhalation and exhalation) and conscious breathing.
There are lot of breathing exercises (Pranayama) in Yoga. By doing it regularly, it regulates breathing and rejuvenates each and every cells in the body.
Pranayama also gives so many other physical & mental benefits.