# How to reduce fatigue at the gym

Tags: weight-loss, workout, cardio, stamina

I used to go to the gym 2-3 years ago. But now I rarely go, because after a break I can't really do any cardio: after 7-15 minutes at a treadmill I get really tired. I usually go 10-14kmph and going slower just feels wrong. After 15-20 minutes once I got dizzy and it hurt breathing in, but I was going slightly faster than usual. I also have a pretty high heartbeat when I run

So my problem is that in order to feel less tired running I need to run. But most I can do is 15minutes. I've tried 5-6 times recently, but it's always the same thing.

How do you deal with this exhaustion? What are the tricks to quickly get your stamina back after a long break. Maybe I should try something else, rather than treadmills

I want to get back to weights, but before that get my stamina back. I'm 21, weighing 105kg, 192cm height. So I would like to get rid of 5kg before I start doing weights again.
I used to be able to comfortly run 30min before doing weights and after for another 30min. Weighing 90kg at a comfortable stage, with no clear sight of being overweight.

In response to duplicate - My question is not how to lose weight quickly, but how to quickly regain stamina (possibly when health situation isn't ideal).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much cardio to lose body fat fast and healthy](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/853/how-much-cardio-to-lose-body-fat-fast-and-healthy)

Comment: @FredrikD My goal isn't necessarily to lose weight :) If anything, I'm comfortable staying at 95-100kg

Comment: You tried 5-6 times over what kind of time span? One week, or six months?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann about a year. All times tried to start with cardio, but then gave up and next session was just doing weights.

Comment: Seems to me like you're very out of shape, and need to start with walks/slow jogs over longer periods of time in order to get a base stamina level.

Comment: Yeah I'm not reading it as a duplicate of "using cardio to lose body fat".

Comment: Weights and cardio are entirely different exercises. If you're lifting properly, then there is essentially no relation between your ability to do them. Someone could run a marathon but still not be able to pick up a heavy book, while a massively strong powerlifter might struggle jogging a mile.

Comment: @Benubird true, but it helps being able to go for longer sessions after you're good at cardio

Comment: I don't have an answer, but rather a question: what are you eating? Exhaustion could be due to eating food which lacks basic "good" nutritional properties...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I used to go to the gym 2-3 years ago. But now I rarely go, because after a break I can't really do any cardio: after 7-15 minutes at a treadmill I get really tired....I've tried 5-6 times [over the course of a year], but it's always the same thing.

Your problem is that you're not giving your body a chance to get better at cardio. One session where you get tired isn't enough. You need to do that one session, then *go back* a day or two later and do it again. Nobody can expect to be good at something they don't do. (It happens, but those are happy accidents.) You're not doing cardio, so you're bad at it.

Try going to the gym and doing your 15 minutes of cardio, then *no matter how it goes*, going back two days later and doing 15 minutes again. Repeat this process until 15 minutes isn't so bad, then do 20 minutes, and so on. Don't wait for your body to get good at cardio without working at it.

Comment: I understand that I actually need to do it in order to get better at it... but man was it so much easier before. Must be the extra weight that I gained. Are there any suggestions for cardio apart from running?

Comment: @Amir Cardio means essentially "anything that makes you sweaty and out of breath", so all sorts of options exist—swimming, running, calisthenic circuits—but none of these will be both easier and more effective.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest working on intervals. Dave makes a good point in his answer that progress basically requires you to work at a high intensity day after day (with rest days, of course), but it sounds like you're running yourself into the ground on these workouts. Try spacing out shorter runs with periods of walking. When you start to get tired, walk for a time. The big catch is that, at least in my experience, trying to judge intervals by feel seldom works. I wind up pushing myself too hard for too long on the runs, and the walking periods can easily extend too long as well because it's comfortable and I feel like I'm not "fully recovered" even when I'm fine to go.

Try something like the [Couch to 5k](http://www.c25k.com/) program. At your level, the first several workouts are going to be too easy, so try starting somewhere around week 3 or 4. Go through the workout and run the intervals (there are various phone and tablet apps for this) even if it seems too easy, and gauge your position from there.

Answer (score 3):

For me its all mental, I go with full of energy and excitement to gym.
Gym is a place where I have trained my mind to forget all the good/bad things and just complete my sets.

I would recommend you to stick to a strict workout plan(a written) and try to finish it before leaving gym.

Answer (score 1):

I love intervals or circuits for this. Changing up the routine helps me catch my breath, while still working my body. It also fights my biggest problem with running, jogging, biking, walking: Freaking boredom.

As Dave said, though, cardio is basically doing stuff vigorously. You know what's vigorous, fun cardio? Dancing. Try to find a retro dance scene, like Swing, Blues, or Country or some other folk dancing. You'll find interesting people, you won't be falling into old cycling habits, you'll be doing something until you're sweaty and breathless...

... And let's be honest: one of them may be interested in practicing some *other* forms of cardio. ;) That's what I call a win-win scenario!

Answer (score 1):

For the heartbeat and fat burning the best suggestion from me is to start skipping rope. Just do the basic jump. [Skipping rope detailed information](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skipping_rope)
On the above page under the title Health Benefits

> **Skipping as exercise**
> Skipping may be used for a cardiovascular workout, similar to jogging or bicycle riding. This aerobic exercise can achieve a "burn rate" of up to 700 calories per hour of vigorous activity, with about 0.1 calories consumed per jump. Ten minutes of jumping rope is roughly the equivalent of running an eight-minute mile.

Start with 2 sets of 15-20 later increasing within a period of 5 days. This shall get your cardiovascular goals along with burning some calories.

There's no trick or short cut for healthy body. It only comes with dedication and consistency. So what ever be your exercise try to be consistent in it and also increase once comfortable upto that level